# Number based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to generate a number based on a condition. 
When there is yes in column 'Stop' in the partition of a Client ordered by Start_Date, the Dense Rank has to start over. So I tried several things but it's stil not what I want.
My table with current number and expected number

```
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
| Client_No | Start_Date | Stop | Current_No | Expected_No |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-1-2018  |  No  |      1     |      1      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-2-2018  |  No  |      2     |      2      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-3-2018  |  No  |      3     |      3      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-4-2018  |  Yes |      1     |      1      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-5-2018  |  No  |      4     |      2      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     1     |  1-6-2018  |  No  |      5     |      3      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     2     |  1-2-2018  |  No  |      1     |      1      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     2     |  1-3-2018  |  No  |      2     |      2      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     2     |  1-4-2018  |  Yes |      1     |      1      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     2     |  1-5-2018  |  No  |      3     |      2      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
|     2     |  1-6-2018  |  Yes |      2     |      1      |
+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------------+
```

The query I used so far:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Client_No, Stop ORDER BY Start_Date ASC)
```

This seems not to be the solution because it counts onwart from the value 'no', but I don't no how to handle this in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve such a Gaps-And-Islands puzzle is to first calculate a rank that starts with the 'Yes' stops.

Then calculate the row_number or dense_rank also over that rank.

For example:

> ```
> create table test 
> (
>   Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
>   Client_No int,
>   Start_Date date,
>   Stop varchar(3)
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into test 
> (Client_No, Start_Date, Stop) values
>   (1,'2018-01-01','No')
>  ,(1,'2018-02-01','No')
>  ,(1,'2018-03-01','No')
>  ,(1,'2018-04-01','Yes')
>  ,(1,'2018-05-01','No')
>  ,(1,'2018-06-01','No')
>
>  ,(2,'2018-02-01','No')
>  ,(2,'2018-03-01','No')
>  ,(2,'2018-04-01','Yes')
>  ,(2,'2018-05-01','No')
>  ,(2,'2018-06-01','Yes')
> ```

> ```
> select *
> , row_number() over (partition by Client_no, Rnk order by start_date) as rn
> from
> (
>   select *
>   , sum(case when Stop = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Client_No order by start_date) rnk
>   from test
> ) q
> order by Client_No, start_date
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Client_No | Start_Date          | Stop | rnk | rn
> -: | --------: | :------------------ | :--- | --: | :-
>  1 |         1 | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   0 | 1 
>  2 |         1 | 01/02/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   0 | 2 
>  3 |         1 | 01/03/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   0 | 3 
>  4 |         1 | 01/04/2018 00:00:00 | Yes  |   1 | 1 
>  5 |         1 | 01/05/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   1 | 2 
>  6 |         1 | 01/06/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   1 | 3 
>  7 |         2 | 01/02/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   0 | 1 
>  8 |         2 | 01/03/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   0 | 2 
>  9 |         2 | 01/04/2018 00:00:00 | Yes  |   1 | 1 
> 10 |         2 | 01/05/2018 00:00:00 | No   |   1 | 2 
> 11 |         2 | 01/06/2018 00:00:00 | Yes  |   2 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f00a8154044826114e69f914d61f0444)*

The difference between using this:

```
row_number() over (partition by Client_no, Rnk order by start_date)
```

versus this:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by Client_no, Rnk order by start_date)
```

is that the dense_rank would calculate the same number for the same start_date per Client_no & Rnk.

Comment: Thanks you LukStorms, this seems to work perfectly. The extra row in my table works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Below is one approach which gives you the output you want. You can see as a live/working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e901f98179081b129167b09f934e6d1d).

The steps involved are:

1. Create an adjusted stop value where we mark Stop as Yes for the first ever row for every customer
2. Create a separate table which only includes the rows where we will want to start/restart counting
3. For each of the rows in this new table we also add an end data, which is basically the date of the next row for every customer, or for the last row a date in the future
4. We join the original data table with the new table and run a sequence based on this new calculation

```
-- 1. Creating adjusted stop value
data_adjusted_stop as
(
select      *,
            case when row_number() over(partition by Client_No order by Start_Date asc) = 1 then 'Yes' else Stop end as adjusted_stop
from        data
),

-- 2. Extracting the rows where we will want to (re)start the counting
data_with_cycle as
(
select      Client_No,
            row_number() over(partition by Client_No order by Start_Date asc) adjusted_stop_cycle,
            Start_Date
from        data_adjusted_stop
where       adjusted_stop = 'Yes'
),

-- 3. Adding an End_Date column for each row where we will want to (re)start counting
data_with_end_date as
(
select      *,
            coalesce(lead(Start_Date) over (partition by Client_No order by Start_Date asc), '2021-01-01') as End_Date
from        data_with_cycle
)

-- 4. Running a sequence partitioned by Client_No and the stop cycle
select      data.*,
            row_number() over(partition by data.Client_No,      data_with_end_date.adjusted_stop_cycle order by data.Start_Date asc) as desired_output_sequence
from        data
left join   data_with_end_date
            on data_with_end_date.Client_no = data.Client_no
where       data.Start_Date >= data_with_end_date.Start_Date
and         data.Start_Date < data_with_end_date.End_Date 
order by    1, 2
```